# In chrome tab key is not working properly

Tags: html, tabs, accessibility

In the chrome browser tab key is not working properly.

I am using two input text fields in my site.

```
<div>
   <input type="text" tabindex="1" 
          class="loginBox valid" name="userName" id="userName">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" 
           class="loginBox" tabindex="2">
</div>
```

styles:
background ,border,width,opacity.

While using tab key in chrome cursor is not going to second field at first click of tab key. It is going at second press of tab key.

But it works fine in all browsers except chrome and safari.

Comment: Is this your code as in your issue? or have you taken part of the code to show us?

Comment: This works fine. You will need to post more code or a link to your page. Any chance js is interfering?

Comment: thanks ..but its not working its breaking some where..how to work tab key using jquery

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem with all browsers that I used.

1. Press F12 into your  Google Chrome (dev console).
2. Open your application form
3. Into developer console, open "Console" tab and enter the code bellow:

```js
setInterval(function() {console.log(window.onkeydown)}, 1000);
```

The javascript console will print the "window.onkeydown" function, if this function wasn't override, the console will show "null" values. If you use any UI library that override window.onkeydown, you'll identify on this console what event was overriding this callback.

In my case, we're using modal components with angular and bootstrap. When we show the modal, from 3rd party library change the "window.onkeydown" event and blocks some keys to be forwarded to my screen.

Comment: Always outputs null with each key press

Answer (score 1):

Delete that tabindex field in both input tags !!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine in Chrome 18/dev Mac:
http://jsfiddle.net/uxwv7/

Comment: yes.its works fine in this.but in my app.<label for="userName" class="loginFormLabel trx" id="loginFormNickNameLabel" style="opacity: 0; display: none;">Email
           (or) Nick Name</label> label is inside the input fields

Comment: ? You mean the input fields are inside the `label`s?  Either way, `tabindex` should remain a property of the `input` tags.

Comment: <div><div><input></div><label></div> ..my code is arranged in this order..i had adjusted label to visible inside input text like place holder(not place holder) fading text using opacity.

Comment: @karthick k, you need to post your *real* code to get help with it.